# Como chamar um método dentro de outro método?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um quiz. Usando como resposta RadioButton. Até aqui criei usando o método onClick em cada RadioButton, mas não é eficaz.

Então gostaria de chamar cada pergunta `ask1();`, `ask2();` dentro do método `rate(View view)` e a partir de lá calcular a pontuação total das respostas do usuário mostrando uma Toast.

Mas ao chamar por exemplo o método `ask6();` dentro do `rate(View view);` da erro. Mesmo eu colocando o parâmetro view `ask(view);` por que rate tem é uma view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    double rating = 0;
    String userAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ask1( View view ) {
        //See if checked
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        //Do some if checked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answer1_ask1:
                if (checked) {
                    rating += 1;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                if (checked) {
                    rating -= 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    public void ask2( View view ) {
        //is checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        //Do some
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answer1_ask2:
                if (checked) rating -= 1;

            case R.id.answer2_ask2:
                if (checked) rating += 0.5;

            case R.id.answer3_ask2:
                if (checked) rating += 0.5;
        }
    }

    public void ask3(){
        EditText answer = findViewById(R.id.answer1_ask3);
        userAnswer = String.valueOf(answer.getText());

        if (userAnswer.equals("Láctea")) {
            rating += 1;

        } else if (userAnswer.equals("Via Láctea")) {
            rating += 1;

        } else {
            rating -= 1;

        }

    }

    public void ask4(View view){
        //See if checked
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        //Do!
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answer1_ask4:
                if (checked) {
                    rating += 1;
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.answer2_ask4:
                if (checked) {
                    rating -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.answer3_ask4:
                if (checked) {
                    rating -= 1;
                    break;
                }

        }
    }

    public void ask5(View view){
        //is checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();

        //Do it now!!!!
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.answer1_ask5:
                if(checked){
                    rating += 1;
                }
            case R.id.answer2_ask5:
                if (checked) {
                    rating -= 1;
                }
        }
    }

    public void ask6(View view){
        //is checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();

        //Please do fast!
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.answer1_ask6:
                if(checked){
                    rating += 1;
                }
            case R.id.answer2_ask6:
                if(checked){
                    rating -= 1;
                }
        }
    }

    public void rate( View view ) {
        // ask6(View view); Why can't I call?
        // ask6(view); Why bug?

        ask6();
        Toast.makeText(this, ("Oi "+ rating ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rating = 0;
    }



    /*
    public void ask3( View view ) {
        //was wrote?
        //String answer = ((EditText)view).getText(findViewById(R.id.answer1_ask3)).toString();

        //was wrote?
        EditText answer = findViewById(R.id.answer1_ask3);
        String userAnswer = String.valueOf(answer.getText());

        String rightAnswer1 = "Via Láctea";
        String rightAnswer2 = "Láctea";

        //do some
        if(userAnswer == rightAnswer1) rating += 1;
        if (userAnswer == rightAnswer2) rating += 1;
        else rating -= 1;

        // if (userAnswer == "a"){


    }
    */
}
```

Parte do XML:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer1_ask6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer1_ask6"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer2_ask6"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer2_ask6"/>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:text="RESPONDER"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="rate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

=================== Adicionando uma edição =============

Na documentação do Android, tem um exemplo de como usar o RadioButton:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_pirates:
        if (checked)
            // Pirates are the best
        break;
    case R.id.radio_ninjas:
        if (checked)
            // Ninjas rule
        break;
}
```

}

O bom desse método, é que eu só tenho que jogar o id de cada RadioButton e uso o switch pra executar tudo de uma vez. Então editei o meu código pra fazer case de cada RadioButton que tenho no quiz. Ficou assim:

```
public void askRadioButton(View view){
    //is checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();

    //Do it now!!!!
    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.answer1_ask1:
            if (checked) {
                rating += 1;
                break;
            }
        case R.id.answer1_ask2:
            if (checked) rating -= 1;
            break;

        case R.id.answer2_ask2:
            if (checked) rating += 0.5;
            break;

        case R.id.answer3_ask2:
            if (checked) rating += 0.5;
            break;

        case R.id.answer1_ask4:
            if (checked) {
                rating += 1;
                break;
            }
        case R.id.answer2_ask4:
            if (checked) {
                rating -= 1;
                break;
            }
        case R.id.answer3_ask4:
            if (checked) {
                rating -= 1;
                break;
            }
        case R.id.answer1_ask5:
            if(checked){
                rating += 1;
            }
        case R.id.answer2_ask5:
            if (checked) {
                rating -= 1;
            }
    }
}

public void rate( View view ) {
    askRadioButton();

    Toast.makeText(this, ("Oi "+ rating ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    rating = 0;
}
```

Mas ainda não consigo chamar corretamente o novo método. Se eu remover o parametro view, o resto do código não funciona.

Comment: Você não está passando o parâmetro `view` ao chamar o método `ask6();`

Comment: já tentei passar o parametro view, mas da erro. Por que rate é um método de um botão do meu xml @ValdeirPsr

Comment: Entendi. Então substitua `((RadioButton)view).isChecked();` por `((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID_DO_RADIO_BUTTON)).isChecked();` e passe o parâmetro `view`

Comment: Tem como prover quais são as classes de cada método? E também quais objetos você tem que instância essas classes?

Comment: Oi @ValdeirPsr eu descrevi melhor o problema. Pode olhar por favor?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu descrevi melhor o problema, você poderia dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O primeiro erro é que você não está passando o parâmetro `view` para o método `ask6`.

> Erro: Não compila

**Explicação:** Se você define um parâmetro em um método, você **deve** passar um parâmetro ao chamar ele. O *java* **não** permite que você chame um método que precisa de parâmetro, sem usar parâmetro.

---

O segundo erro é que você está passando um `Button`, mas, no método `ask6`, você está tentando "converter" para um `RadioButton`.

> Erro: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: *android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton*

**Explicação:** Aqui você **não** vai conseguir converter um `Button` em um `RadioButton`, apesar dos nomes serem semelhantes, o *android* não permite que você possa converter dois objetos totalmente diferente.

Você só consegue converter ambos para `View`, pois eles herdam métodos e atributos de uma classe chamada `View`.

---

**Então, como fazer?**

Antes de mais nada defina um `id`, no XML, para seu `RadioGroup`.

```
<RadioGroup
...
android:id="@+id/ask6" />
```

**Agora vamos ao código *java*.**

No *java*, vamos remover o parâmetro `view` do método `ask6`, ele não é útil.

Próximo passo é remover todo o conteúdo do método `ask6`, vamos fazer de uma forma diferente.

```
public void ask6(){

    /* Nessa linha iremos capturar o RadioGroup da pergunta 6 e vamos capturar o ID do RadioButton marcado */
    int buttonChecked = ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ask6)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    switch (buttonChecked) {
        /* Iremos comparar o ID do RadioButton marcado com o ID da Resposta 1 (da pergunta 6) */
        case R.id.answer1_ask6:
            rating += 1;
        break;

        /* Iremos comparar o ID do RadioButton marcado com o ID da Resposta @ (da pergunta 6) */
        case R.id.answer2_ask6:
            rating -= 1;
        break;

        /* Caso nenhum dos buttons seja marcado, exibimos um Toast. */
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selecione a resposta da pergunta 6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
```

Dessa forma podemos chamar o método `ask6` sem o parâmetro `view`.

```
public void rate( View view ) {
    ask6();
    Toast.makeText(this, ("Oi "+ rating ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    rating = 0;
}
```

---

Caso você queira verificar a pontuação de todos de uma só vez, basta **seguir o passo a passo.**

**Passo 1:** No XML vamos definir o atributo `android:tag="NOTA"`. Substitua a nota por valores positivos ou negativos. Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.RadioButtonsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/ask6">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1_ask6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resposta 1 de 6"
            android:tag="+1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2_ask6"
            android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resposta 2 de 6"
            android:tag="-1"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/ask7">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1_ask7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resposta 1 de 7"
            android:tag="+0.5"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2_ask7"
            android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resposta 2 de 7"
            android:tag="-0.5"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:text="RESPONDER"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="rate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Passo 2:** No *java* vamos definir dessa forma **leia os comentário no código para entender**:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RadioButtonsActivity extends Activity {

    private float rating = 0;

    /* Armazene aqui todos os IDs dos RadioGroup */
    List<Integer> radioGroups = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(R.id.ask6);
        add(R.id.ask7);
    }};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_buttons);
    }

    public void ask(){

        for (Integer radioGroupId : radioGroups) {
            /* Nessa linha iremos capturar o RadioGroup da pergunta 6 e vamos capturar o ID do RadioButton marcado */
            int buttonChecked = ((RadioGroup) findViewById(radioGroupId)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            /* Vamos capturar o RadioButton marcado */
            RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(buttonChecked);

            /* Atribuimos "0" para caso a resposta não tenha sido marcada */
            Float point = 0f;

            try {
                /* Vamos capturar a pontuação que definimos no atributo android:tag */
                point = Float.parseFloat(radioButton.getTag().toString());
            }  catch (NullPointerException ignored) {}

            /* Vamos somar/subtrair da variável rating */
            rating += point;
        }
    }

    public void rate( View view ) {
        ask();
        Toast.makeText(this, ("Oi "+ rating ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rating = 0;
    }
}
```

> Siga esse padrão, não tente fazer como tem na demonstração de tal site, provavelmente ele não vai se encaixar na solução que você busca. Utilize os exemplos para aprendizado, apenas.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta!!! Eu sou um estudante e sua resposta me ajudou muito. Mas eu fiz algumas alterações no meu código pra funcionar usando switch, você pode ver? Eu vou postar agora aqui.

Comment: Posso ver sim..

Comment: Opa! eu tentei postar aqui, mas os comentários são realmente curtos. Então editei a minha pergunta adicionando o código que eu refiz. Se puder olhar eu realmente agradeço, pois tô empacado nisso aqui.

Comment: Tipo... Você não seguiu as dica que dei, logo no início postei o porque todos erros. A única coisa que você alterou foi adicionar um monte de IDs no Switch.

Alterei minha resposta. Adicionei algumas informações e um outro jeito de verificar todas as respostas.